# Aggregating Categorical Variables w/ Dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm attempting to create a stacked bar chart based on two non-numeric variables using Dimple.js and D3. Dataset contains roughly 50,000 points, each categorized in two ways (sectors and channels). Ideally, the x-axis is a series of categories (channels), while the y-axis represents a count of those same categories. I hope to stack the bar chart based on a 2nd series of categories (sectors).

The code below does the job of stacking, but as seen in the image, instead of displaying an aggregate count of all the channels, it just indicates the presence of a channel in a particular sector.

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "channel"); 
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y","channel");
      myChart.addSeries("channel", dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.draw();
```

Image: https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/t31.0-8/11223612_10207362634082002_162421922019209911_o.jpg

Is there a way using Dimple to do this aggregating? Can't seem to find it in the docs. Anyone willing to help/with experience dealing with this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your code example has a typo in it which is not the problem here.  To be clear for anybody reading this answer in the future it should read (otherwise my answer makes no sense!):

```
myChart.addSeries("segment", dimple.plot.bar);
```

When you create a measure axis on a category it counts the distinct values of that category, in your case each channel/segment will of course on have a single distinct channel meaning it gets a value of 1.

The problem you are facing here is that Dimple aggregates your data to the least granular level defined in your code (in this case channel/segment) before it does anything else.  That means that a dataset like this:

```
channel      segment    brand      sales
----------------------------------------
Ecommerce    Sports     Nike        2000
Ecommerce    Sports     Reebok      3000
Ecommerce    Sports     Adidas      4000
Retail       Sports     Nike        5000
Retail       Sports     Reebok      6000
Retail       Sports     Adidas      7000
Retail       Sports     Puma        8000
```

Would become:

```
channel      segment
--------------------
E-commerce   Sports
Retail       Sports
```

So any detail of counts would be lost.

You therefore have 2 choices both of which require you to do something to your data, unless you already have them available.  The first assumes you have a unique column (or at least unique for each Channel/Segment combination) in my example that would be Brand.  This would mean you could alter your code to:

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "channel"); 
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y","brand");
myChart.addSeries("segment", dimple.plot.bar);
myChart.draw();
```

And your data would now be grouped up as:

```
channel      segment      dist brands
-------------------------------------
Ecommerce    Sports                 3
Retail       Sports                 4
```

The alternative is to add a column of 1s to your data:

```
channel      segment    brand      sales     count
--------------------------------------------------
Ecommerce    Sports     Nike        2000         1
Ecommerce    Sports     Reebok      3000         1
Ecommerce    Sports     Adidas      4000         1
Retail       Sports     Nike        5000         1
Retail       Sports     Reebok      6000         1
Retail       Sports     Adidas      7000         1
Retail       Sports     Puma        8000         1
```

Which would be summed as with any other numeric column:

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "channel"); 
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y","count");
myChart.addSeries("segment", dimple.plot.bar);
myChart.draw();
```

To give the same results

```
channel      segment      sum of count
--------------------------------------
Ecommerce    Sports                  3
Retail       Sports                  4
```